# Oracle SID INS-35075 - Keep the same SID

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sid

How I can maintain the same SID?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTahz.png

Edit later: I buy a laptop and I install the 11g. I tested and it works fine. But the user in Windows 7 was *Maria*, so I deleted and copy all stuff to my user *John*, and here is the problem, because sqldeveloper not recognize the database. So I delete all files and the folder with product 11.2.0 etc., and retry from the beginning the installation, but I get the SID error INS-35075.

Comment: Please edit your question and add more details.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

on Linux CentOS

```
[root@localhost / ] rm -rf tmp/OraInstall*
[root@localhost / ] rm -rf /etc/oratab

[root@localhost / ] su - oracle  (login as oracle user for reinstalling)

export DISPLAY="your machine ip from where you connected to linux for Interactive Oracle Installer Display":0

[oracle@localhost / ]  ./runInstaller
```

Answer (score 1):

The error code ins-35075 indicates that the SID you are attempting to use is already in use.

You must first un-install using the OUI (Oracle Universal Installer) before trying to use the same SID.

Comment: Check in the actual install directory on your C drive - or if you have the CD it should be on it.

Comment: @JohnSP: try to search for "Installer" or "Universal" in start menu search-box. Alternatively, search your SID name in Windows registry (regedit.exe), delete from registry everything related to Oracle's SID (don't forget to backup !), then try again to install